# Is it possible to quickcheck functor properties of the function type?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, functor, quickcheck

I am trying to implement my own functor instances and quickcheck them, and have run into issues on typeclasses which are not instances of `Eq`, namely `(->)` and `IO`. My attempts result in a `No instance for (Eq ...)` error.

In the `(->)` case I had run into a similar error with `Show`, i.e. `No instance for (Show ...)`, and was able to fix that by adding a `Show (a -> b)` instance as suggested in an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23504950/haskell-no-instance-for-show). It would seem that I might be able to solve also the lack of `Eq` instances by adding them similarly. However, [this question on function equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906628/equality-of-functions-in-haskell) notes that that in Haskell creating an instance of `Eq (a -> b)` is equivalent to the halting problem and therefore impossible.

I'm not sure whether creating an instance of `Eq IO a` is possible. In the `IO` case I also run into a `No instance for (Arbitrary ...)` error.

**Is there some way to quickcheck the functor properties of the function type `(->)`? Is there some way to do the same for the `IO` type?**

My code is as follows.

```
import Prelude hiding (Functor, fmap)
import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck.Function

class Functor f where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

instance Functor IO where
  fmap h f = f >>= (pure . h)

instance Functor ((->) e) where
  fmap = (.)

data T a = T

prop_functorid :: (Functor f, Eq (f a)) => T (f a) -> f a -> Bool
prop_functorid T x = fmap id x == x

prop_functorcompose :: (Functor f, Eq (f c)) => T (f a) -> T b -> T c -> f a -> Fun a b -> Fun b c -> Bool
prop_functorcompose T T T x (apply -> g) (apply -> h) =
  fmap (h . g) x == (fmap h . fmap g) x

instance Show (a -> b) where
  show a= "function"

prop_function :: IO ()
prop_function = do
  quickCheck $ prop_functorid (T :: T (String -> String))
  quickCheck $ prop_functorcompose (T :: T (String -> String)) (T :: T String) (T :: T String)

prop_io :: IO ()
prop_io = do
  quickCheck $ prop_functorid (T :: T (IO String))
  quickCheck $ prop_functorcompose (T :: T (IO String)) (T :: T String) (T :: T String)

main = do
  prop_function
  prop_io
```

Comment: There is an arbitrary instance for functions `(CoArbitrary a, Arbitrary b) => Arbitrary (a -> b)` you can then test for equality for functions - if you evaluate pointwise - i.e. you generate arbitrary `a` and compare the `f a` values

Comment: for IO - you need to write your own Arbitrary instance - and except for the trivial instance `arbitrary = fmap pure . arbitrary` I cannot think of a reasonable one.

Comment: Usually, functions for QuickCheck should be represented by its `Fun` type.

Comment: You might want to use the `(.&&.)` operator from `Test.QuickCheck.Property` to combine properties, instead of creating an IO action and checking individually each property every time.

Comment: There is absolutely no way to verify the functor instance for `IO`, because your function (properly) requires `Eq (f a)` but you cannot have an instance `Eq (IO A)` for any type `A`. Functions are another story - a bit difficult, but [doable](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.9.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Function.html).